# Docusign - generate Authorization code for getting Auth token

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to create a embeded sign in url from backend webservice and open that url in the mobile application for signing.

For that in backend first of all i need to get Auth token.

To fetch auth token i need to get Auth code. For this i need to build a url with redirect url and when i open this url it will be redirected to given redirect url with auth code.

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?
   response_type=code
   &scope=YOUR_REQUESTED_SCOPES
   &client_id=YOUR_INTEGRATION_KEY
   &state=YOUR_CUSTOM_STATE
   &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
   &login_hint=YOUR_LOGIN_HINT
```

But this process is manual and auth code from this is valid for 2 minutes only. So each time i have to build url and get auth code.

Is there any automated programmatical way to fetch auth code or generate auth code which will not expire.

Answer (score 0):

**If the signer is also the DocuSign account user,** then Authorization Code Grant is the right way to go.

It sounds like you're not implementing authorization code grant correctly:
You redirect the user's browser to the DocuSign OAuth service (account.docusign.com for production, account-d.docusign.com for development).

After the user finishes authenticating with DocuSign, the authentication service will redirect the user's browser to your **redirect_uri**, which you supplied earlier.

Your application, initiated via the **redirect_uri** then exchanges the authorization code for an access token. There's nothing "manual" about this process other than manually entering the email/password for authentication.

**JWT Grant when the DocuSign account user is not present**
It could also be that the signer does not have an account on the DocuSign system. (This is the more common situation.) Signers do not need DocuSign accounts, only **senders** do.

In this case, your application should use the JWT Grant flow to impersonate a DocuSign account user--either a real person or a "system account" such as "Payroll Department."

The JWT Grant flow is used to obtain an access token. Then your server-side software would use the API to send the envelope, and then to obtain an embedded signing ceremony URL. Next, redirect the user's browser (on the phone) to the signing ceremony URL. After the signer signs, the DocuSign signing ceremony software will redirect the user's browser back to your application.